# Get the element of list or index of list while "for" looping with step in range

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am looping through a list with step as below:

```
list_of_names = ["james", "jack", "jill"]

for i in range(1, len(list_of_names) * 6 + 1, 7):
    print(i, i + 6)
```

Now I want to get the index of the element or the iteration number so that i can print the current element of the list.
So I want the output to be

```
(1, 7, "james")
(8, 14, "jack")
(15, 21, "jill")
```

or

```
(1, 7, 0)
(8, 14, 1)
(15, 21, 2)
```

How can I do that?

Note: I am using python2.

Comment: Use `enumerate`!? @user001

Comment: Are you maintaining some critical legacy codebase? If not, there is no good reason to use Python 2 these days.

Comment: @mzjn Yes. I am maintaining a legacy codebase which might take a year to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic isn't identical to your version, but maybe you want to achieve something similar to this?

```
for i, name in enumerate(list_of_names):
    print(i * 7 + 1, (i + 1) * 7, name)
```

In your version, as `list_of_names` grows, the number of elements that aren't printed will increase by one at each list length `n*6 + 1`, `n` being a positive integer. For instance, when the length is 7, only the first 6 items will be printed (i.e., `i` taking on values [1, 8, 15, 22, 29, 36], but not 43) and by length 13, only 11 elements would be printed.

If possible, you should be using Python 3 instead. Python 2 is no longer maintained.

Comment: I am maintaining a legacy codebase. So I have to use python2 until it is migrated.

Comment: Given the fact that the end of Python 2 was announced over 12 years ago I really wonder why someone waits with the migration until Python 2 is not only dead but a rotting corpse.

Comment: @user001 please see my edit. The logic of my answer is slightly different than in your question. In your version, at every length of `n*6 + 1`, `n` being a positive integer, the number of items printed from the list will decrease by one. So at length 7, only 6 items will be printed with your version. At length 13, only 11 items would be printed, and so on.

Comment: @frippe Yes. My code has that error. Your code and logic is correct. Thank you for correcting the error also.